# Rendering new path from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am wanting to know if it is possible to render a path from my rails application in Javascript?

I want to call my new.html.haml file if the user changes options in my dropdown.

I have this function in Javascript

```
contract_type = $("#payer_contract_type_code option:selected").val(); 

$(document).change(function(){
    contract_type_change = $("#payer_contract_type_code option:selected").val();
    if (contract_type_change != contract_type) {
        //I WANT TO RENDER NEW PATH HERE
    }

});
```

I want to call "new.html.haml" file which contains this

```
- content_for(:title, t('payer_contracts.page_titles.new'))

- content_for :article do
  - if @contract_type == 'GLOBAL_CONTRACT_SUB_TYPE'
    .bar
      %h1= t('payer_contracts.add_global_payer_contract')
    .common-main-container
      = render 'global_form'
  -else
    .bar
      %h1= t('payer_contracts.add_bpci_contract')
    .common-main-container
      = render 'bpci_form'
```

Is it possible to call this file in my javascript function?